# React Native - .app file on Xcode Simulator asking for Bundle URL

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, metro-bundler

I want to generate .app or .ipa file for my react native application , so that i can use it for the Automation testing on simulator using Appium.
This is the command am using for building the app file for simulator (using Fastlane)

```
lane :buildForAutomation  do |options|

xcodebuild(scheme: "CavionNovus",
           xcargs: "-configuration 'Debug' -sdk 'iphonesimulator' -destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' "
           )

end
```

This will generate a .app file . i have installed the same on the simulator using the below command

```
xcrun simctl install booted ./CavionNovus.app
```

It will install the app successfully , while launching it will wait for few seconds and show error message on the screen.

[image]

Its asking for metro bundle packager .
So my Doubts are

Do we need a packager like metro bundler to run the .app file in simulator ?
If so how can i add it during the build process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `xcodebuild(scheme: "CavionNovus", xcargs: "-configuration 'Debug' -sdk 'iphonesimulator' -destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator'")` you're building an ipa in debug mode. To be able to run your app without Metro Bundler, you will have to change the configuration to `release`.